# Docker Compose Return Message ERROR: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: remount /, flags: 0x84000: permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-layer

i pull docker image and create container using docker-compose, after running the command `docker-compose up` i got message `ERROR: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: remount /, flags: 0x84000: permission denied`. why docker-compose return this message?.
please any one can help me, thanks.

[image]

Comment: I wonder you just exhausted inode space. Can you try `df -i`? Or run docker cleanup `docker system prune -a --volumes`

Comment: have you tried changing the storage , overlay/overlay2 has problems with older linux kernels; try using vfs instead and see if that works